# perform inner Join for 3 tables in EF

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

Hello i'm trying to implement inner join for three tables 
I start with two tables it gives me the appropriate result.

But i don't know how to implement join for three tables?
could anyone help?

This is the select statement i would like to do it in EF:

```
SELECT
  capt_ar AS VehicleState,
  cont_name,
  vehl_drivername,
  vehl_name,
  vehl_entrancedate,
  vehl_customsdec,
  cont_rampid
FROM Container
  INNER JOIN
  Vehicle ON Container.cont_vehicleid = Vehicle.vehl_VehicleID
  INNER JOIN
  Custom_Captions ON Vehicle.vehl_state = Custom_Captions.Capt_Code
WHERE capt_family = 'vehl_state'
      AND vehl_Deleted IS NULL AND cont_Deleted IS NULL
      AND vehl_ClearanceCompany = 471
```

[image]

> Updated: Query Result in SQL server
>
> Update: this is what i tried to do but no output

```
var result = (from cont in db.Containers
              join veh in db.Vehicles on cont.cont_vehicleid equals veh.vehl_VehicleID
              join cap in db.Custom_Captions on veh.vehl_state equals cap.Capt_Code
              where cap.Capt_Family == "vehl_state && veh.vehl_Deleted == null && cont.cont_Deleted == null && veh.vehl_ClearanceCompany =="+p.pusr_CompanyId
              select new { cap.Capt_AR, cont.cont_Name, veh.vehl_drivername, veh.vehl_Name, veh.vehl_entrancedate, veh.vehl_customsdec, cont.cont_rampid }
```

Comment: Well add another JOIN to the Two you already claim to have coded

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected result?

Comment: If you dont tell us something **useful** about the other tabel you want to JOIN like at least its foreign key then you are going to have to do it yourself

Comment: I want to perform inner Join for the three tables: Container,Vehicle,Custom_Captions these are the three tables

Comment: @RiggsFolly do you read my above comment? i mention out the three tables i want to make join on it

Comment: But still nothing about the new table you want to JOIN to the query

Comment: @RiggsFolly there's no new table, all i want is to know how to code the Sql query to one give me the same result using EF

Comment: Oh right. SO is not a code conversion service

Comment: @RiggsFolly  i tried to code it  but i couldn't? could you help ?

Comment: What does not work about what you have?

Comment: @RiggsFolly  tried to perform inner join for two tables:Container,Vehicle but i stopped when adding the Custom_Captions table.

Comment: You stopped, or the query fails? If you stopped, then keep going, run it and see what gets generated, a table or an error

Comment: @RiggsFolly please notice the updated statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = (from con in db.Containers
                             join v in db.Vehicles on con.cont_vehicleid equals v.vehl_VehicleID
                             join cust in db.Custom_Captions on v.vehl_state equals cust.Capt_Code
                             where cust.Capt_Family== "vehl_state" && v.vehl_Deleted==null && con.cont_Deleted==null && v.vehl_ClearanceCompany==p.pusr_CompanyId
                             select new
                             {
                                 cont_name=con.cont_Name,
                                 vehl_Name=v.vehl_Name,
                                 VehicleState=v.vehl_state,
                                 vehl_drivername=v.vehl_drivername,
                                 vehl_entrancedate=v.vehl_entrancedate,
                                 vehl_customsdec=v.vehl_customsdec,
                                 cont_rampid=v.vehl_rampid
                             }
                             ).ToList();
```